# Allow client to upload ESRI shapefile in OpenLayers 3

Tags: postgis, shapefile, openlayers

I want to build functionality to upload ESRI shapefile and overlay it on map using OpenLayers 3. Once user cross checked I want to save to PostgreSQL/PostGIS table.

So far as I Googled I am not getting any resources. Is there any way to do in OpenLayers 3?

Comment: By client do you mean 'user' or do you mean web browser?

Comment: I would say that your nil results through search are correct, you won't be able to upload a shapefile directly into OpenLayers of any version, as its a binary format not intended for web view.  You might though consider a solution based on use of a WFS-T service

Comment: from browser user will upload shapefile something like http://gipong.github.io/shp2geojson.js/

Comment: Have a look at shp2geojson.js library: https://github.com/gipong/shp2geojson.js

Comment: that is in leaflet so

Comment: Library is neutral, you can easly use it in OpenLayers. You can see this from examples, which are for Leaflet and Google Maps.

Comment: Your comments, don't really match your question, please edit the question to add more details of what you are trying to do, what you have found, what you have tried

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `shp2geojson.js` library it is possible to load ESRI shapefile and convert it to standard GeoJSON object that can then be used to create overlay in OpenLayers 3.

Below is simple example of such usage. Shapefile `Mexico_and_US_Border.zip` is loaded directly from https://opendata.arcgis.com/ site and then added as overlay over OSM map. The only critical part is when reading features from GeoJSON object with `ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures` method. Here the right input and ouput projections have to be specified.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Load SHP overlay</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/ol3/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="lib/ol3/ol-debug.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jszip/jszip.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jszip/jszip-utils.js"></script>
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jszip-utils-ie.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.15/proj4.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/shp2geojson/preprocess.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/shp2geojson/preview.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>      
      var featureStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'red',
          width: 1
        })
      });

      var sourceOSM = new ol.source.OSM();

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: sourceOSM
          })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2
        })
      });
      var vectorSource;
      var vectorLayer;

      loadshp({
        url: 'https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/e735940321bd4383bab528a91bf526f8_0.zip?outSR=%7B%22latestWkid%22%3A3857%2C%22wkid%22%3A102100%7D',
        encoding: 'utf-8'
      }, function(geojson) {
           var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojson, {defaultDataProjection: 'EPSG:4269', featureProjection: sourceOSM.getProjection()});
           vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
             features: features
           });
           vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
             source: vectorSource,
             style: featureStyle
           });
           map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
         }
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```